# "heroku create" gives me error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial. On chapter 1.4.1, when I type "heroku create" I get the following:

```
/home/pharaoh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.0/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:343:in `hputs': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/pharaoh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.0/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb:109:in `create'
    from /home/pharaoh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:111:in `run'
    from /home/pharaoh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.0/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pharaoh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /home/pharaoh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I appreciate any help. I have looked around in Google and here, but did not find a similar case.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post *exactly* what you typed in, and not just the output? The output isn't terribly helpful if we don't know what you were putting in. Could be a simple typo, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - update your heroku gem and all will be fine.

There was an issue in 2.16 gem yesterday for exactly this error which was fixed in 2.16.1

https://github.com/heroku/heroku/commit/56e8fa3d417f508d8a609fb6c3ce8dbd16930bc8

Comment: no worries. You must have installed the heroku gem in the 2hr window that it was in a bad state.